# How do I convert "7-1-2014" to "07-01-2014" in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, text, workbench

I have already gone through part of the process to convert my text to a proper date:

**7-jan** -> **7-1** -> **7-1-2014** 
(note: dd-mm-yyyy)

However, I am now required to change the 7-1-2014 format to 07-01-2014 in order to change the text to a date.

Is there an easy way to do this?
Am not too experienced but have a basic understanding of queries and functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're looking for something like this :

```
select STR_TO_DATE('7-1-2017', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('7-1-2014', '%e-%m-%Y');
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('7-Jan-2014', '%e-%M-%Y');
```